# Skyrim highest level(combat/character lv)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Anyone know the answer to this? I have reached level 54, and wonder how much longer I can go..

Answer (score 3):

Since 1.9 there is no longer a highest level in skyrim but it use to be lvl 81

source: http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2013-03-04-new-skyrim-pc-patch-1-9-effectively-removes-the-overall-level-cap

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Maybe because link part of this answer is longer than non-link one? And without access to linked material (I can't open it, for example) we can't really know when did it change, what other things may effectively cap levelling character etc.